# Way to log some datas in file during migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I have many migrations to operate and I searching to log some datas in files depending conditions (for example, log every external links which no longer work for each imported content). I have many ideas but they're not optimal (not very clean or optimize) or I don't know how to implement them:

- Open my file, log my datas and close it directly when it's necessary, via a custom process plugin during the migration. It's the more simple. The problem: Opening the file is consuming and on a migration where I can log many thousand links, I will do this each time, which will have an impact on the duration of my migration.
- Via a subscriber, I can open my file before my migration via an eventSubscriber, and closed it when my migration is finished (always with the eventSubscriber). But in this case, I don't know how to use it during the migration. Other idea: I can save temporary my datas with State API and save it in the file when the migration is finished, then, delete the state (which seems the more proper for the moment).
- I though to use a logger class implementation but I'm not sure how to define my file and how it works (I looked the file SysLog.php but I'm not sure to understand where I should open and close my file).

Any better way (or explanation for logger or access to my file after open it with an eventSubscriber).

Comment: I didn't know this function. But I don't think it's a good idea: I give one example in my description but in the present migration, I have 3 kinds of datas to save in 3 csv files which will be send to the customer after.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe you can have an array that is passed by reference and add data to it through each migration. When all migrations are done you can then convert the array to a csv file look here for more info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108157/php-array-to-csv. Don’t know if it will work just an idea :)

Comment: The problem is not the create the file and save my datas in a csv modele. The problem is to find an optimized way to do that to don't increase excessively the duration of my migration, regard the first version (without all transformations asked) has already a duration of more 1 hour.

Comment: That’s why I suggest having an array that is passed by reference

Comment: So I have the same problem than with my file: How I pass my array on my eventSubscriber when the migration is finished to save it? Reason why I want use the state API: To recover my array.

Comment: You can create a simple class that a one property e.g migration data that is an array, that class then has a method to add data to that array and a method to get the array.

Comment: That has one property*

Comment: In this case, my array should be static in my class because my object will be initiate for my plugin which is call each time I read a data in my migration but should be read in the postMigration event to be save in the file. I'm not fan of this solution.

Comment: Ok good luck then :)